# What does to be featured mean

Tags: expressions, verbs, idioms, nouns, comprehension

In the "About the author" page of a book published by Wiley (for dummies) there is a sentence about Joelle Jane Marshall, the author of the book, like this: Jo has been featured in "The Career Stylist's Inspiration Lounge" and has held workshops for "Girl Summit" alongside "Childline" and the "NSPCC"

My question is: What is "The Career Stylist's Inspiration Lounge"? Is this a name of a magazine? Or sth else? And what do we mean when we say somebody has been featured in ....?

I would be very grateful if you help me.

Comment: Please do not repost.  [To be featured and some proper nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/566669/to-be-featured-and-some-proper-nouns)

Comment: That question was closed and I had to post this question which is the edited version of previous question.

Comment: It means that (if it's a magazine) it has included a prominent article about her - or the equivalent if it's a website.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful information. But one question remains: is it a magazine or website or ...? I didn't find any reference about it in the net. I would be very grateful if someone helps me.

Comment: The 'remaining question' is not about the English language per se; it is a request for the answer to a general knowledge question. If necessary, it might be possible to contact the actor's press secretary to ask about 'The Career Stylist's Inspiration Lounge'; it doesn't seem widely mentioned on the internet.